# Java's getWheelRotation() always returns 1 or -1

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a program that relies on user input, and one of the things that I need is the program to recognize how many "clicks" the mouse wheel has rotated forward or backwards in a single sroll.

For this I have used the `MouseWheelListener` and the function `getWheelRotation()`, which:

> Returns the number of "clicks" the mouse wheel was rotated, as an integer.

However, it only ever seems to return -1 (if rotated away from the user) or 1 (if rotated towards it). For example, if the wheel is rotated 3 "clicks" away from me, the program will return -1 three times instead of -3 (the movement being done continuously, of course).
Here is the code I'm using for that particular task:

```
private class Handler implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener {

     public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event){        
         System.out.println(event.getWheelRotation());   
     }

//Some more code

}
```

Is there any error in my code? If not, is it possible to implement this another way so the function returns the desired values?

Comment: `and one of the things that I need is the program to recognize how many "clicks" the mouse wheel has rotated forward or backwards in a single sroll.` - why do you think you need this? If we know the real requirement (not your attempted solution), we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: @camickr: Regardless, the Javadocs the OP quoted imply the return value will be total clicks not just direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an count function that is called every time the wheel is turned and counts how often it was "clicked" in a private member variable.

```
private int counter = 0;

private count(int x) {
    counter += x;
    System.out.println("The wheel was turned " + counter + " times.");
}

private class Handler implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener {

    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event){
        count(event.getWheelRotation());
    }

    //Some more code
}
```

The output after "klicking" the wheel 3 times would be:

```
The wheel was turned 1 times.
The wheel was turned 2 times.
The wheel was turned 3 times.
```

Comment: You may want to add some detail to your answer - why your answer works etc t make it more complete.

Comment: That will be of no use, as the counter will not reset to 0 after I stop scrolling. Also, I only want a single output for every scroll.

Comment: The problem is that the computer doesn't know it when you stop scrolling. Every "klick" is a seperate action for the computer. There is not something like 10 "klicks" at once. The computer acts for each "klick" because it isn't defined how long the time between two "klicks" can be.

Comment: You could add a click listener for example that looks for a click and if one was found it does the output. That means the user has to stop the process of scrolling manualy. Just take out the output in the count function and add a second listener.